# Revert uncheck on checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good morning, What I need to do is, when the client click on a checkbox I need to revert that action in some scenarios but doing this.

```
 $("#foo").attr('checked');
 or
 $("#foo").attr('checked', 'checked');
 or
 $("#foo").attr('checked', true);
```

And looking with the firebug indeed the checked is marked, but still visually does not change, and there´s no check on the component.

Any idea how to make it works

Comment: use  $("#foo").prop('checked', true);

Comment: Is disabling the checkbox an option? Otherwise this can easly confuse the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 $("#foo").prop('checked', true);
```

Documentation [Here](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Comment: I thought that I already test that option as well. Thanks!